# Erro ao passar parametro para SqlCommand parametrizando a tabela

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Estou tentando passar parâmetro no meu `select` e esta estourando a exceção:

> É necessário declarar a variável de tabela `"@p_tabela"`.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sql = "SELECT Id FROM @p_tabela";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_tabela", tabela));

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // Estoura erro aqui
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Ja tentei com isto tambem:

- `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_tabela", tabela);`
- `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
  command.Parameters.Add("@p_tabela", SqlDbType.VarChar);
  command.Parameters["@p_tabela"].Value = tabela;`

Segunda tentativa use daqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8
Imagem do erro:

[image: Descrição da exceção]

Comment: Precisamos saber mais sobre o erro. De qualquer forma eu já vi em códigos seus que você usa exceção do jeito errado.  Elimine esse `try-catch` porque ele não tem utilidade alguma. Leia mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o Também deveria usar mais `using` e não `finally`.

Comment: Bom dia Leo.. tudo certinho.. Cara .. para PARAMETROS do argumento WHERE eu utilizo exatamente com você demonstrou no segundo modo..: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_tabela", tabela);. Como saco pouco de C# minha pergunta é.. o FROM @p_tabela ACEITARIA o nome da tabela como PARAMETRO?? Saca o que quero dizer? Para resolver isso RAPIDAMENTE do modo lusitano eu colocaria assim..:  var sql = "SELECT Id FROM " + tabela; Já que você ela como variável acho que não faria mal algum.. Mas como eu disse uma maneira de resolver NOW :) Não sei se atenderia sua necessidade. Qualquer coisa é só falar :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza, perdao a demora, eu fiz justamente isso pra testar, estava com a mesma duvida.... E realmente era isso... coloquei where para confirmar e funcionou...

Answer (score 1):

O sistema de interpolação [`SqlCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) só permite usar variáveis em certos locais, o nome da tabela não é um local permitido. Então o jeito seria fazer com interpolação normal. Mas lembre-se isto é perigoso em muitos casos, se o dado vier externo tenha certeza que você é muito bom nisso, caso contrário fará coisas erradas e terá buracos de segurança. Seria algo assim:

```
$"SELECT Id FROM {tabela}"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Table.cs).

Não se esqueça do comentário acima, tem muita coisa errada neste código (inclusive porque dá para perceber que não entende porque está fazendo certas coisas, isso é perigoso), ainda que funcione.

Comment: bom dia Maniero.. cara.. eu pensei tu falou :)

Comment: @Maniero, obrigado pelo esclarecimento... Voce pode me indicar uma maneira segura de fazer isso?

Comment: Procure nas minhas respostas, já falei bastante sobre o assunto. Mas é algo que depende de estudo, não tem receita de bolo. Um dos erros que eu já percebi que você faz é copiar exemplo de documentação como se fosse receita de bolo, aquilo está lá pra demonstrar o mecanismo, não para você copiar no seu código, todos aqueles códigos são ruins para uso em produção.

Comment: Opa, estou super feliz que voce me respondeu exatamente como eu queria a minha pergunta... Vou parar de fazer isso, sei que é ruim para mim e para o meu aprendizado, mas da proxima vez, voce poderia ser um poquinho mais especifico e me dar uma referencia, um norte, para que eu estude de maneira correta e certeira sobre o assunto, ta bom?! Não é nada produtivo eu procurar em mais de 5.000 respostas... Obrigado